# nodejs: valid command line prompt doesn't exec or spawn with ENOENT error

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

I have a bash command (debian 10, GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)):

```
documents=("/data/sice.pdf" "/das00/12ser.pdf");bash ./clean-pdfs.sh "${documents[*]}"
```

that works when I paste into terminal.

However invoking it with either exec or spawn fails without giving clear error message.

When I ran it with `exec` I got some complaints about the brackets. Remembering the output is quite large, I opted for `spawn`

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
command = `documents=(${pdfPaths});` + 'bash ./clean-pdfs.sh "${documents[*]}"'
console.log(command);

const subProcess = require('child_process')
const lsChildProcess = subProcess.spawn(command)

lsChildProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
})

lsChildProcess.on('error', function(err) {
 console.log(err);
});
```

and after running this nodejs script I get the following error message that isn't very helpful (i changed the paths for security reasons):

```
{ Error: spawn documents=("/data/Traa.pdf" "/dater.pdf");bash ./clean-pdfs.sh "${documents[*]}" ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall:
   'spawn documents=("/daice.pdf" "/daer.pdf");bash ./clean-pdfs.sh "${documents[*]}"',
  path:
   'documents=("/dace.pdf" "/daer.pdf");bash ./clean-pdfs.sh "${documents[*]}"',
  spawnargs: [] }
```

Comment: Maybe try `subProcess.spawn(command, { shell: true })`

Comment: @GOTO0 thanks that worked! but still not seeing the output string from the command. just says DONE

Comment: @GOTO0 actually can't get the output from this. tried spawnSync and still getting exit code 2 and complaint about the bracket `(`

Comment: I've posted an answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `shell` is required here to (both conditions apply):

- parse multiple commands separated by ";"
- run commands that are not executable, like assigning an environment variable with `document=`.

To have the output of the spawned process printed to the console, we can use the option `stdio: 'inherit'`.

Both settings are documented here: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options

And here is my version of the code that I was able to test succesfully on a zsh terminal. I'm using `spawnSync` because it's easier to handle without a callback, but `spawn` works just as well.

```js
const pdfPaths = '"/data/sice.pdf" "/das00/12ser.pdf"';

command = `documents=(${pdfPaths});` + 'bash ./clean-pdfs.sh "${documents[*]}"'
console.log(command);

const subProcess = require('child_process')
subProcess.spawnSync(command, { shell: true, stdio: 'inherit' })
```